# MySQL Query to get profit and loss on asset by order history

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone I am getting a problem with the MySQL query and had confusion. I want to achieve profit and loss on assets from order history.

1. IGNORE coin_current_price in output not needed.
2. resultBuy = TotalBuyingPrice / totalCoinQtyBuy
3. if sellingPrice_Per_Coin is greater than resultBuy then it will be profitable and vice-versa for loss.
4. Coin Name, coin_currency are the same then it will be called as a single entity. if any of these conditions don't meet then it will create a new row for that item like usdt and INR
5. admin_id will be the user id only of that user data will show.

MySQL Query - For Two Table buy_table and sell_table

```
  CREATE TABLE buy_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  coin_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_qty TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_buy_price TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_current_price TEXT NOT NULL,
  admin_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  priority TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_currency TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sell_table (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  coin_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_qty TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_buy_price TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_current_price TEXT NOT NULL,
  admin_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  priority TEXT NOT NULL,
  coin_currency TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (1, 'BTC', '1', '$10', '$10', '11', '1','inr');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (2, 'ETH', '1', '$10', '$10', '11', '1', 'inr');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (3, 'BTC', '1', '$10', '$10', '11', '1', 'inr');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (4, 'ETH', '4', '$10', '$10', '11', '1', 'inr');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (5, 'BTC', '3', '$10', '$10', '11', '1', 'inr');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (6, 'WRX', '1', '$1',  '$1', '11', '1', 'inr');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (7, 'WRX', '1', '$1',  '$1', '11', '1', 'usdt');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (8, 'WRX', '1', '$1',  '$1', '11', '1', 'inr');
INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES (9, 'WRX', '1', '$1',  '$1', '11', '1', 'usdt');


INSERT INTO sell_table VALUES (1, 'ETH', '1', '$50', '$50', '11' , '1', 'inr');
INSERT INTO sell_table VALUES (2, 'BTC', '1', '$50', '$50', '11' , '1', 'inr');
```

Final Output Will Be Like Below

```
| Coin Name | coin_currency | Buying Price | CoinQty | PricePerCoin | SellingPrice | SoldQty | ProfitLoss | Stock | admin_id |
| --------- | ------------- | ------------ | ------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------- | ---------- | ----- | -------- |
| BTC       | INR           | $50          | 5       | $10          | $50          | 1       | $40        | 4     | 11       |
| ETH       | INR           | $50          | 5       | $10          | $50          | 1       | $40        | 4     | 11       |
| WRX       | INR           | $2           | 2       | $1           | 0            | 0       | 0          | 1     | 11       |
| WRX       | USDT          | $2           | 2       | $1           | 0            | 0       | 0          | 1     | 11       |
```

This is the table structure if required with an online query run. [Link for table](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xqxp9pc5)

Comment: @nnichols this is dummy data. i updated my question. date no use for my app, coin_id and coin_currency will be sent from app. i just added this for dummy data in MySQL query. but it will be useful in my java code.

Comment: I updated my question may be this time it make some sense. Please check new table data i updated the link. thank you for your time @nnichols

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) One last try! Include your CREATE TABLE statements in code blocks in your question. Include your sample data as either INSERT statements or markdown tables. Change your example output to a markdown table.

Comment: I hope this one is correct @nnichols I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would combine the two tables into one transactions table but for this answer I will leave the tables split as you have them.

Firstly, let's address the issues with the datatypes used in your two tables. TEXT is not the appropriate datatype for any of your columns. I have changed them to what I believe to be more appropriate types.

```
CREATE TABLE buy_table (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  coin_name VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  coin_qty SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  coin_buy_price DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  coin_current_price DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  admin_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  priority TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  coin_currency CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

/* I am omitting the amended sell_table as it is identical in all but name */

INSERT INTO buy_table VALUES
  (1, 'BTC', 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (2, 'ETH', 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (3, 'BTC', 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (4, 'ETH', 4, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (5, 'BTC', 3, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (6, 'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (7, 'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'usd'),
  (8, 'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (9, 'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'usd');

INSERT INTO sell_table VALUES
  (1, 'ETH', 1, 50, 50, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (2, 'BTC', 1, 50, 50, 11, 1, 'inr');
```

For this query I have chosen to aggregate the data on each side of the union in the derived table. This could be done in just the outer select list but it made some of the calculations more readable. As you suggested this will be run with the context of an admin_id I have included this as a predicate on the inner queries and not included the admin_id in the outer select list -

```sql
SELECT
    `coin_name`,
    UPPER(`coin_currency`) AS `coin_currency`,
    SUM(`total_paid`) AS `buying_price`,
    SUM(`num_bought`) AS `coin_qty`,
    SUM(`avg_paid`) AS `price_per_coin`,
    SUM(`total_received`) AS `selling_price`,
    SUM(`num_sold`) AS `sold_qty`,
    ROUND((SUM(`avg_received`) - SUM(`avg_paid`)) * SUM(`num_sold`), 2) AS `profit_loss`,
    SUM(`num_bought`) - SUM(`num_sold`) AS `stock`
FROM (
    SELECT
        `coin_name`,
        `coin_currency`,
        SUM(`coin_qty`) AS `num_bought`,
        0 AS `num_sold`,
        SUM(`coin_qty` * `coin_buy_price`) AS `total_paid`,
        0 AS `total_received`,
        ROUND(SUM(`coin_qty` * `coin_buy_price`) / SUM(`coin_qty`), 2) AS `avg_paid`,
        0 AS `avg_received`
    FROM buy_table
    WHERE `admin_id` = 11
    GROUP BY `coin_name`, `coin_currency`
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        `coin_name`,
        `coin_currency`,
        0 AS `num_bought`,
        SUM(`coin_qty`) AS `num_sold`,
        0 AS `total_paid`,
        SUM(`coin_qty` * `coin_buy_price`) AS `total_received`,
        0 AS `avg_paid`,
        ROUND(SUM(`coin_qty` * `coin_buy_price`) / SUM(`coin_qty`), 2) AS `avg_received`
    FROM sell_table
    WHERE `admin_id` = 11
    GROUP BY `coin_name`, `coin_currency`
) tx
GROUP BY `coin_name`, `coin_currency`;
```

This would be cleaner if all the transactions were in a single table.

**UPDATE** - tables combined into single transactions table

```sql
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  type ENUM('buy', 'sell') NOT NULL,
  coin_name VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  coin_qty SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  coin_buy_price DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  coin_current_price DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  admin_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  priority TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  coin_currency CHAR(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO transactions VALUES
  ( 1, 'buy',  'BTC', 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  ( 2, 'buy',  'ETH', 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  ( 3, 'buy',  'BTC', 1, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  ( 4, 'buy',  'ETH', 4, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  ( 5, 'buy',  'BTC', 3, 10, 10, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  ( 6, 'buy',  'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  ( 7, 'buy',  'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'usd'),
  ( 8, 'buy',  'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  ( 9, 'buy',  'WRX', 1,  1,  1, 11, 1, 'usd'),
  (10, 'sell', 'ETH', 1, 50, 50, 11, 1, 'inr'),
  (11, 'sell', 'BTC', 1, 50, 50, 11, 1, 'inr');

SELECT
    `coin_name`,
    `coin_currency`,
    `total_paid` AS `buying_price`,
    `bought_qty` AS `coin_qty`,
    ROUND(`total_paid` / `bought_qty`, 2) AS `price_per_coin`,
    `total_received` AS `selling_price`,
    `sold_qty`,
    ROUND(IFNULL(((`total_received` / `sold_qty`) - (`total_paid` / `bought_qty`)) * `sold_qty`, 0), 2) AS `profit_loss`,
    `bought_qty` - `sold_qty` AS `stock`
FROM (
    SELECT
        `coin_name`,
        UPPER(`coin_currency`) AS `coin_currency`,
        SUM(IF(`type` = 'buy', `coin_qty`, 0)) AS `bought_qty`,
        SUM(IF(`type` = 'sell', `coin_qty`, 0)) AS `sold_qty`,
        SUM(IF(`type` = 'buy', `coin_qty` * `coin_buy_price`, 0)) AS `total_paid`,
        SUM(IF(`type` = 'sell', `coin_qty` * `coin_buy_price`, 0)) AS `total_received`
    FROM transactions
    WHERE `admin_id` = 11
    GROUP BY `coin_name`, `coin_currency`
) tx;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a8bdcc45fbdc3f51395c109bd8e278cf)

Comment: I merge two tables into a single table as per your opinion. how i can now solve this query into one.

Comment: @PankajPatidar I have added an example